# Pandas - understanding output of pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

Here is my example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student': ['A',  'B', 'B'],
    'Assessor': ['C',  'D', 'D'],
    'Score': [72, 19, 92]})
df = df.pivot_table(
    index='Student',
    columns='Assessor',
    values='Score',
    aggfunc=lambda x: x)
print(df)
```

The output looks like:

```
Assessor    C       D
Student              
A          72     NaN
B         NaN  [1, 2]
```

I am not sure why I get '[1,2]' as output. I would expect something like:

```
Assessor    C       D
Student              
A          72     NaN
B         NaN     19
B         NaN     92
```

Here is related question:

if I replace my dataframe with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student': ['A',  'B', 'B'],
    'Assessor': ['C',  'D', 'D'],
    'Score': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo']})
```

The output of the same pivot is going to be

```
Process finished with exit code 255
```

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

[`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations) finds the unique values of the index/columns and aggregates if there are multiple rows in the original `DataFrame` in a particular cell.

Indexes/columns are generally meant to be unique, so if you want to get the data in that form, you have do something a little ugly like this, although you probably don't want to.

```
In [21]: pivoted = pd.DataFrame(columns=df['Assessor'], index=df['Student'])

In [22]: for (assessor, score, student) in df.itertuples(index=False):
    ...:     pivoted.loc[student, assessor] = score
```

For your second question, the reason that `groupby` generally fails if that there are no numeric columns to aggregate, although it seems to be a bug that it completely crashes like that.  I added a note to the issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10326).